keyboard.add_hotkey печатает нажатую клавишу
Собственно код:
import keyboard

keyboard.add_hotkey('w', lambda: keyboard.write('333'))
keyboard.add_hotkey('e', lambda: print('777'))
keyboard.wait('esc')

При нажатии w и e выводится сначала нажатый хоткей, а потом сам текст.
Т.е. w333 и e777 соответственно. А хотелось бы без лишнего)).
Подскажите, что я делаю не так.

А с чего вы решили, что это кейборд печатает нажатую клавишу? Это вы нажимаете клавишу на клавиатуре, закономерно она и печатается. Кейборд в данном случае - просто перехватывает ваше нажатие, но его не блокирует.

Да, я не так выразился, но сути это не меняет. Мне нужно, чтобы этот символ не печатался. Есть возможность это заблокировать?

В рамках кейборда можно отключить нажатие конкретной клавиши, но это убивает возможность обрабатывать её через хоткей. Можно написать свою реализацию хуку и там уже обрабатывать нажатие + блокировать само нажатие.

В общем сделал так
import keyboard

def foo():
    keyboard.send('backspace')
    keyboard.write(s)

keyboard.add_hotkey('w', foo)
s = 'text'
keyboard.wait('esc')

